# How to get POSIXct to work with ==

Tags: r, comparison, posixct

I've noticed that `==` doesn't seem to work with POSIXct:

```
a <- structure(c(1466985600, 1464652800, 1464652800, 1464652800, 1472428800, 
1466985600, 1468195200, 1472428800, 1472428800, 1474848000, 1464652800, 
1468195200, 1476057600, 1464652800, 1472428800, 1472428800, 1460332800, 
1460332800, 1460332800, 1460332800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC")

a
```

> [1] "2016-06-27 UTC" "2016-05-31 UTC" "2016-05-31 UTC" "2016-05-31 UTC" "2016-08-29 UTC" "2016-06-27 UTC" "2016-07-11 UTC"
>   "2016-08-29 UTC"
>        [9] "2016-08-29 UTC" "2016-09-26 UTC" "2016-05-31 UTC" "2016-07-11 UTC" "2016-10-10 UTC" "2016-05-31 UTC" "2016-08-29 UTC"
>   "2016-08-29 UTC"
>       [17] "2016-04-11 UTC" "2016-04-11 UTC" "2016-04-11 UTC" "2016-04-11 UTC"

```
table(a=="2016-06-27")
```

> ```
> FALSE 
>    20
> ```

```
table(a=="2016-06-27 UTC")
```

> ```
> FALSE 
>    20
> ```

```
table(a==as.POSIXct("2016-06-27 UTC"))
```

> ```
> FALSE 
>    20
> ```

```
table(a==as.POSIXct("2016-06-27"))
```

> ```
> FALSE 
>    20
> ```

```
a[a=="2016-06-27"]
```

> ```
> character(0)
> ```

How can I get this to work?

This would work, but I really hope it's not my only option:

```
a[a==1466985600]
```

> ```
> [1] "2016-06-27 UTC" "2016-06-27 UTC"
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time zone needs to be separate, unless specified in the `format` argument.  Your code embeds the time zone in the string, but the default formats are `"%Y-%m-%d"` and `"%Y/%m/%d"` , so the time zone gets cut off and it defaults to the current locale.  We can find the time zone of `a` with `attr()`, since it's an attribute of `a`.

```
table(a == as.POSIXct("2016-06-27", tz = attr(a, "tzone")))

# FALSE  TRUE 
#    18     2
```

Comment: Similar but possibly simpler:  `a ==  utctime("2016-06-27", tz="UTC")`.  Requires [anytime](https://cran.r-project.org/package=anytime).  Another concern for `POSIXct` and equality is, of course, that `POSIXct` "really" is a floating-point number which has its own set of issues -- see R FAQ 7.31.